# Error 401 Streaming Twitter Api with Java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I am using Streaming Twitter API but I get this error:
HTTP ERROR: 401

Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/filter.json'. Reason:

```
    Unauthorized
```

I use the following OAuth authentication:

```html
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("XX")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret("XX")
                .setOAuthAccessToken("XX")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("XX")
```

However, I have worked correctly with REST, for example with this code:

```html
       User user = twitter.showUser(nick);
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: In my case it is failing with Problem accessing '/1.1/user.json'. Reason Unauthorized. At the same time, instead of ConfigBuilder if i use twitter4j.properties things work fine.